# Ignoring requests to images etc. when greping server logs

Tags: linux, bash, unix, grep

I'm looking to pull out various metrics from some server logs. The first is the total number of requests to just pages, not images, CSS files etc.

So I want to include requests like:

```
140.77.167.177 - - [01/Apr/2016:22:40:09 +1100] "GET /bad-credit-loans/abc/ HTTP/1.1" 200 7532 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)"
```

but ignore requests like:

```
158.165.213.180 - - [01/Apr/2016:23:00:55 +1100] "GET /assets/img/lenders/png/insurance.png HTTP/1.1" 200 17866 "https://www.example.au/lp/tradie-loans/?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=mobilead&utm_campaign=abcs/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1.1; SM-G920I Build/LMY47X; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/48.0.2564.106 Mobile Safari/537.36 [FB_IAB/FB4A;FBAV/70.0.0.22.83;]"
```

`grep "GET " | wc -l` will get me **all** requests; how to I disregard those that are in a range (*.png, .css, .jpg and .js), and how do I extend this to ignore *any* file?

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
grep -Ev '\.(png|jpg|css|js)' file.log
```

Comment: Thanks. And to extend this to disregard *any* file, I've tried `grep -Ev '\.*' file.log` but it's giving me no matches. Any thoughts?

Comment: I mean not just .png, .js, but any request that is for a *file* (rather than a page).